# NGINX - conflicting server name "www.foo.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I can't figure out why does `nginx` raises error `conflicting server name`.

My project runs on two domains - `foo.com` and `bar.com`. After setting up `nginx`, I've installed `let's encrypt` certificate which adds a server block in `sites-available/myproject`.

Then I tried to set redirects from `www.foo.com` and `www.bar.com` to `foo.com` and `bar.com` but these two domains doesn't work.

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.foo.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.bar.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

The same shows `error.log`

This is the `sites-available/myproject`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.bar.com;
    return 301 $scheme://bar.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.foo.com;
    return 301 $scheme://foo.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name foo.com bar.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/futilestudio/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}

server {
    if ($host = bar.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = foo.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name 178.128.xxx.xxx foo.com bar.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

So what I want is to redirect all `www` to `non-www` which are secured. Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading. The usual problem is backup files left behind by editors in the `sites-enabled` folder.

Comment: Thanks, there was added another block for www ssl. Don't know where it was from, probably from alternate universe... Reinstalling nginx helped.